# "Daemon failed to start- please check your daemon log for errors" message

Tags: daemon

Daemon won't start and I keep getting the below error in the Daemon Log. I have tried to start monerod.exe manually, by running it as an administrator, but it didn't work. How can I get the Daemon working again?
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

2018-05-11 12:30:19.495 10260   ERROR   net.http    contrib/epee/include/net/http_client.h:456  Unexpected recv fail
Error: Problem fetching info-- rpc_request:

Comment: Are you running the GUI?  On Windows?  Is it v0.12.0.0?

Comment: That's a timeout. Several of those were fixed in the current release-0.12 branch.

Comment: I am using the latest release and still experiencing this problem of the Daemon failing to start?

Comment: @MoneroUser7878 - Did you upgrade to GUI v0.12 before or after April 6?

Comment: I upgraded last week.

Comment: What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: It is monero wallet GUI the latest upgrade... Does anyone know?

Comment: I have exact same problem. What's the fix?